# Using undirectional Relation query patterns

Tags: cypher

The Neo4J reference says all Relation are directional.  But in the Cypher section, the Relationship syntax says both directional an undirectional patterns are used (page 11 in Neo4j Developer Manual 3.0).

Even after looking at the Cypher query examples, I still don't understand what 
a undirectional Relation pattern means.

Can someone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876378/neo4j-one-directional-two-directional-relationships

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.